# Obtain g-force from accelerometer readings

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer

I want a label that shows the current g force the iPhone is experiencing. I have code to get information from the accelerometer but I do not know how to send the data to a label to show the current g force. 
Here is my code...

```
if (!self.manager) {
    self.manager = [CMMotionManager new];
}

if (self.manager.isAccelerometerActive) {
    [self.manager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
}

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

[self.manager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:1.0 / 30.0]; // 30 Updates Per Second
[self.manager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"X: %f         Y: %f         Z: %f",accelerometerData.acceleration.x,accelerometerData.acceleration.y,accelerometerData.acceleration.z);
}];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy. You'll want to setup a UILabel in Interface Builder and you'll see a property something like this:

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

Right after your NSLog statement you'll want to insert this code:

```
    self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x=%f, y=%f, z=%f", accelerometerData.acceleration.x,accelerometerData.acceleration.y,accelerometerData.acceleration.z];
```

Of course you may want to make it look nicer but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: BTW, I checked out your website, man, I wish I had that drive when I was 15. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks so much! I just started developing last August after watching a youtube video of how to make a sound board app and realizing that developing was not as hard as I thought it would be. I still have a lot to do though. And thanks for the code too!

Comment: Also I have this code in my viewDidLoad, thats ok right?

Comment: I tested the code and yes it shows in the app but two things, 1 it is not the current g-force, I need it to show the current g-force the phone is experiencing, and 2 it takes like a minute for it to load up. Is that normal

Comment: And yes, viewDidLoad is fine. All the work happens in the NSOperationQueue.

Comment: yeah only once and also how do I have the reading show the g-force instead of just the information.

Comment: You'll need to show more code so we can see why it isn't being called more than once. As for getting actual, calibrated, g-force? Man, that will be a lot of work. First, you are going to need to get rid of a lot of the noise in the signal, read up on high pass and low pass filters. There's code out there for it, possibly even one of Apple's sample apps. That will smooth out your data. Then, you are going to need to calibrate it. 15 years old? You have the math for this. Get a string 1m long and spin it about your head, compute the revs needed for X gees.